# Databases medicine and therapy - animal & human studies, technology readiness level

Tags: genetics, database, stem-cells, clinical-trial, gene-therapy

I am looking for some universal databases that would offer information about drugs and therapies currently in development.

The area of interest is mostly cell and gene therapy. I am looking for anything from preclinical research to clinical trials. I am also searching for data related to technology readiness level of those drugs/therapies.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of clinical trials databases out there. Without more specifics on what you particularly want, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Forgive me. Here is exactly what I would like to find: cell and gene therapy technology readiness level, scientific data including all animal and human studies.

Comment: Sites like [clinicaltrials.gov](https://clinicaltrials.gov/) might be of some use. By specifics -you just want to find about all of them, because there are likely to be hundreds and all in different stages. The data is in the form of publications, which may or may not have been made public.

Comment: Try searching clinicaltrials.gov with the terms "gene therapy" and "cell therapy". If that isn't adequate, feel free to bring what you don't like here.